# How big a sphere would all matter make?

Tags: cosmology

Apologies for the simplicity of this question. I don't have the data at hand to tackle it. It's been bugging me since I thought of it.

If all the matter in the universe was packed into a ball with the density of a neutron star how large would it be, what would be its radius?

Obviously, there is two types of matter. Ordinary matter and dark matter. Since there is no consensus on what dark matter is or even if it exists (for example there are theories of modified gravity) it's seems to me a conservative answer should only take account of ordinary matter.

Comment: $$\text{mass of all matter in the universe}=(\text{density of a neutron star}) \cdot (4\pi/3) \cdot (\text{radius of your ball})^3$$ Solve for the radius.

Comment: This question is just a numbers question, with no physics. If the answer is assuming you can pack it all in some size, and you use a neutron star density you get one answer, if you allow it to have dynamics it'd be different. There is no valid physical assumption

Comment: @Bob bee: It might be just a numbers problem but so is estimating the number of particles in the universe. I'm not saying its great physics. But it is a way of visualising just how much mass there is in the universe when packed as densely as possible. I think this is important, the textbooks that I've looked at about D-Branes, for example, barely mention what they look like, where they are, what size they are. Sure size, shape, place are important in physics?

Comment: Ok. Understood. Was it Eddington who first came out with the number of particles?

Comment: @Bob bee: I'm not sure - it could well have been.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The energy density of the universe is $\sim 10^{-26}$ kg/m$^{3}$. Visible matter constitutes something of the order of a percent of this energy density. The energy density of a neutron star is $\sim 10^{17}$ kg/m$^{3}$. Therefore a neutron star is $\sim 10^{45}$ times denser than the visible matter. Compressing the sphere of the observable universe to that density we take the cubic root which means that the radius would be $10^{-15}$ of the radius of the observable universe or $\sim 10^8$ km. This is about the same as the distance between the Sun and the Earth.

Comment: Wow, the entire universe as a giant atom fits within the solar system!

Answer (score 4):

Given that there are $N = 10^{80}$ baryons in the observable universe, and the nucleon radius is $R_p=0.8\,{\mathrm{fm}}$, go with:

$$ R_{all} \approx N^{\frac{1}{3}}R_p = 2.5\ AU,$$

which is reasonably close to @Philo.